# setDeleted loop resulting in modified entities in saveChanges call

Tags: c#, entity-framework, typescript, breeze

I am trying to do a delete of a hierarchy of objects:

Customer->Orders->OrderItems->OrderItemOptions

I set up a straightforward nested loop trying to even do the operations in the "correct" order as they would have to be done at the database - deleting child records first before deleting parent.

Here's the loop:

```
deleteCustomer(customer: Customer): Promise<void> {
  return this.getCustomerOrderHistory(customer.id).then(orders => {
    orders.forEach(o => {
      o.items.forEach(oi => {
        oi.options.forEach(opt => opt.entityAspect.setDeleted());
        oi.entityAspect.setDeleted();
      });
      o.entityAspect.setDeleted();
    });
    customer.entityAspect.setDeleted();
  });
}
```

The problem is that when the parent object at each level is setDeleted(), a set of duplicate entity records marked as "modified" are added to the changes buffered by the EntityManager. Then when I call saveChanges the ASP.NET/EF back end throws an exception because by the time the UPDATE statements corresponding to those modified records get executed, the DELETEs have already happened so the UPDATEs fail with a FK not found kind of exception.

So what am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a classic case of modifying an array while iterating over it.  When we delete children like this:

```
    o.items.forEach(oi => {
      oi.entityAspect.setDeleted();
    });
```

…each time we call `setDeleted`, it removes the child entity from the parent `items` collection, which is the collection being iterated.  So the next iteration skips the entity in between, and only about half of the entities are actually being set deleted.

The symptoms of this would be a SaveBundle that contains a mix of deleted and modified entities, and (if you are deleting the parent entity), a foreign key violation from the database as you attempt to delete the parent without deleting all the children.

The easy solution is to make a copy of the array before iterating, e.g. using `slice`:

```
    o.items.slice().forEach(oi => {
      oi.entityAspect.setDeleted();
    });
```

Comment: Thanks Steve, that was exactly the problem. I knew that Breeze can add or remove children/parent relations by setting either the FK property (i.e. order.customerId) or the nav property (i.e. order.customer) or both, so figured something like that was going on, but couldn't spot why.